# About disabling a group of checkbox according to another

Tags: php, javascript, forms

first post here, i'll try to be simple:
I need to create a form where participants of a medical convention register to classes, each class lasts 3 hours, so a person who wants to attend to class starting at 10 am cannot register to 11 am, 12pm and 1pm classes, but he can register to 2pm and so on.

There are 3 different classes per hour.

i thought doing this using javascript, but i'm absolutely lost.

Can you please give me a hint on how to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way to do this would be to set a javascript function to run onChange that disabled or enables the other checkboxes.  You would do something like

```
 <input type="checkbox" onChange="enableDisable(11)" name="11" id="whatever">
```

The the pseudocode of your javascript would be:

```
 //Declare function
 //Check the current id and get the next 3 IDs
 //Check the status of the currentid to find out if you checked or unchecked it
 //if you checked it, disable the next 3 ids
 //if you unchecked it, enable the next 3, dependant on whether any of the previous 3 values are checked
```

That last step is going to be a bit of a pain, but that's the basics of how I'd tackle it

Comment: Wow, that was fast. ok. But is it too much to ask a bit more about that function? i'm almost null with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some important point in your question requirements. When user ticks to register class at 10am, they are unable to register both 2 group of class :

- group 1: 11am - 12am - 1pm
- group 2: 9am - 8am - 7am

As you said you're almost "null" with javascrip, I wrote these code for concept purpose only.

First thing you need to do is to download jquery.js file (you can find it everywhere with google), then put the file in the same directory with your register.php file.

The code goes here:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="10" name="convention_time"> 10 am<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="11" name="convention_time"> 11 am<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="convention_time"> 12 am<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="13" name="convention_time"> 1 pm<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="convention_time"> 2 pm<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="15" name="convention_time"> 3 pm<br>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('[name="convention_time"]').live('click',function(){
        var A=$(this);
        var method2call = A.is(':checked')?'attr':'removeAttr'
        var selector = '[name="convention_time"]:lt(3)'
        A.nextAll(selector).add( A.prevAll(selector) )[method2call]('disabled','disabled').attr('checked',false)
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, got another one, the thing is that i have more than one event per hour (3 different classes at 10 am, 2 at 11am for example). Your code enables/disables the 3 correlative checkboxes, but when i added the extra 10 am classes it doesn't work...... ideas? Thanks again